# Transference of angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum

I've been recently wondering looking at the disco ball what will happen if I point the laser beam on reflective ball like this one:

[image]

and start to spin the ball to the speed of around 80% of the speed of light.

Will in such case reflected photons that hit it get imparted with a lateral change of direction?

Just to be clear, I am not interested in space/time issues due to the speed, but the "contact" and "reflection" positions slightly moved due to the speed (if that's even a case here).

Comment: What does the geometry look like in a frame where the mirror is at rest?  Seems to me it's just similar to a light striking a mirror at a very low angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection happens because the electrons in the material are vibrating in response to the incoming wave. When the electrons have a very large net velocity, I expect that they will impart a sideways momentum - in other words, if you aim your laser at the ball when it is stationary, and then speed the ball up, the beam will be deflected off to one side.